# Camel File to List of String

Tags: java, file, csv, apache-camel

I have a csv file:

```
40111683,,NULL,831,242,2015-11-18,2018-09-30,0.250,0.050,0.00000,0.00000,100.00000
40111683,,NULL,831,242,2015-11-18,2018-09-30,0.250,0.050,0.00000,0.00000,100.00000
40111683,,NULL,831,242,2015-11-18,2018-09-30,0.250,0.050,0.00000,0.00000,100.00000
40111683,,NULL,831,242,2015-11-18,2018-09-30,0.250,0.050,0.00000,0.00000,100.00000
```

and the following Camel route:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="deContext" autoStartup="true">
<route>
    <from uri="file:src/data" />
    <to uri="bean:getfile?method=process" />
</route>
</camelContext>
```

The Java Bean:

```
@Service
public class Getfile{

public void process(List<String> strings){

System.out.println(strings);

}
}
```

And this is my error:

> No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile to the required type: java.util.List with value GenericFile[Data-Final.csv]]

How do I marshal a file into a list of Strings in Camel ?

Comment: You can split the file into line by line, and then your bean can process each line as a String. See the Splitter EIP pattern: http://camel.apache.org/splitter

Comment: Split shall split the files in chunk.  file should be marshalled into list of string.

Comment: Try adding: convertBodyTo(List.class) before the to..

Comment: `<route>
    <from uri="file:src/data" /><convertBodyTo type="List.class" />
    <to uri="bean:getfile?method=process" />
</route>` I have already tried this, this doesn't work, it has to marshal

Comment: Change the method to be String which contains the entire content of the file. And then use a LineNumberReader or something to split it to a list in the java code if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use convertBodyTo(String.class).
2. As Claus Ibsen said, split result string to lines
3. Process each line in your custom bean

Comment: `<unmarshal><csv/></unmarshal>` gets me `List<List<String>>` anyways but thats cumbersome to handle as iterations increases

Answer (score 0):

As the error message told you : "**No type converter available**".

So you need write your own type converter to convert GenericFile -> List<String>.

For example :

```
@Component
@Converter
public class MyConverter implements TypeConverters{

     @Converter
     public List<String> GenericFiletoListString(GenericFile<File> file) throws IOException {
             return Files.readAllLines(file.getFile().toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     }
}
```